# Sort word frequencies by descending order of frequencies

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a text file that has word frequencies in the format:

```
word<space>freq
```

where freq is a number. I want to sort the file such as the frequencies are in descending order. For that, I have tried the following:

Read the file into a dictionary:

```
kvp = {}
d = {}
with open("/home/melvyn/word_freq.txt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        word, freq = line.partition(" ")[::2]
        kvp[word.strip()] = int(freq)
```

Sort the dictionary by values:

```
d = sorted(kvp.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Write the sorted dictionary into another text file:

```
with open('/home/melvyn/word_freq_sorted.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(d, f)
```

I have the following questions:
1. Sorting is not happening. Why?
2. How can I add new line between every key-value pair while doing a json.dump? Is there a cleaner way to write the dictionary contents into the text file?

Comment: Oops! typo. I did dump d. Sorry. edited the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `json.dump`, try writing to the file with `file.write`, formatting the strings as needed.

```
import json

kvp = {}
d = {}
with open("a.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        word, freq = line.partition(" ")[::2]
        kvp[word.strip()] = int(freq)

d = sorted(kvp.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])

with open("b.txt", "w") as f:
    for i, v  in d:
        f.write(str(i) + " " + str(v) + "\n")
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this worked like a charm. Thanks a ton :)